# Several files input in one pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

How can I get from this `dataA.dat`

```
a b c 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

and this `dataB.dat`

```
A    B    C
1.1  2.1  3.1
4.1  5.1  6.1
7.1  8.1  9.1
```

*(as shown in the MWE)*
to this:

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

1.1 2.1 3.1
4.1 5.1 6.1
7.1 8.1 9.1
```

where should be *one blank line* between the two data-blocks in the PDF-result.

```
%\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\documentclass[varwidth, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{dataA.dat}
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataB.dat}
1.1 2.1 3.1
4.1 5.1 6.1
7.1 8.1 9.1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{dataA.dat}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread{dataB.dat}\dataB

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index] 0}] {A} {\dataA}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index] 1}] {B} {\dataA}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index] 2}] {C} {\dataA}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[precision=4]{\dataA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For numerical input empty rows would trip an error. Do you need the blank row for typesetting?

Comment: Yes, the result table will be somithing like that 

`
`5 0 * * *
 5 1 * * *
 5 2  * * *
 ...
 5 4  * * *
                 <linebreak !!!> 
 10 0  * * *
 10 1  * * *
 10 2  * * *
 ...
`

Comment: Sry, unable to make linebreaks here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the empty line in the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` and combine the tables with `\pgfplotstablevertcat`. The vertical concatenation requires the col names to be the same so I reordered them. Kind of ugly but if needed it can be embedded to a generic style to ease the overwriting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
a b c A   B   C
1 2 3 1.1 2.1 3.1
4 5 6 4.1 5.1 6.1
7 8 9 7.1 8.1 9.1
}\mytable

\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/a/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 0}},
create on use/b/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 1}},
create on use/c/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 2}},
}

\pgfplotstablenew[columns={a,b,c}]{3}{\dataA}

\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/a/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 3}},
create on use/b/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 4}},
create on use/c/.style={copy column from table={\mytable}{[index] 5}},
}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={a,b,c}]{3}{\dataB}


\pgfplotstablevertcat{\dataA}{\dataB}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[every row no 2/.append style={after row={&&\\ }}]{\dataA}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this is to times the table from dataA(?)

Comment: @cis *facepalm*... I'll fix asap

Comment: OK............ ;)

Comment: @cis Sorry for the delay. Done